# Error in Magento update from 1.4.2 to 1.5.1

Tags: magento

I updated Magento from 1.4.2 to 1.5.1, and I don´t see the customer invoice panel in the  admin section. I have the following error:

```
fatal error: Call to a member function updateBackButtonUrl() on a non-object in /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php on line 152
```

Help, please.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look if you didn't override this file. Otherwise make -f for forcing the update with SSH and it will be all working.

Comment: where?? in the root directory ?? I execute make -f??